# Same Event types for multiple micro-services

Tags: microservices, communication, event-sourcing

In an Event Driven Architecture when there are more than one microservices say A, B  that publish same Event say `Order_Created` and a service C listening to it, performs some actions and publishes an event say `Credit_Reserved` for each new event on this type. My question is, while I can keep a `CorrelationId` to track a chain of events for each instance of a microservice, should different services publish/consume same event types for such an operation or use their own types.

Comment: its fine to have more than one service consume the same event. say order_complete sends an email to the customer and also removes an items from stock. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: If both services A,B consume `Credit_Reserved` in order to change the state of an order and say both A,B will have to check whether an order in say Pending state. Which is kind of unnecessary.

Comment: That seems like a different problem. it's not inherent that they would have to do the same check, or that there aren't ways to avoid the duplication if they do

Comment: In-fact it is this duplication/effort that tempted me to ask this question. I have this scenario where multiple services need to create order and based on `credit_reserved` event proceed with next step. The other available options that I know of are to do a synchronous query to service C for credit-check.

Comment: rewrite your question with the real names of the services and explain the duplication problem you are having.

Comment: User can purchase multiple services from a business, each having different inputs and business flow. All of these involve a purchase and hence a credit-check to begin the purchase process. A Customer service keeps the Credit balance for a user and must check/deduct it for each service ordered. In the old monolith it is a local transaction involving the concerned biz service, customer, invoice and notification components.

Answer (score 2):

The scenario you described is what the [Open Tracing](https://opentracing.io/) standard is designed to resolve.  The Open Tracing standard has several libraries and agregators that help to integrate it with your application.  Basically, you set up a request context when you are calling out of your microservice.  The agregators that visualize the complex interactions can show the layered calls unwinding to the parent context.

Combine that with open tracing in the client layer and you can trace the impact of a button click all the way through the system.